# C how can I decrease my program size

Tags: c, code-size

I am writing a c program for a uController and I managed to fill 32kb with code.

The program is full with the following 'print' function:

```
void print(char *x)
{
    while(*x) {
        SerialWrite(*x++);}
}
```

SerialWrite looks like:

```
void SerialWrite(unsigned char c)

    {
        while(tx_buffer_size>250);
        ES=0;
        tx_buffer_size++;
        if (tx_buffer_empty == 0){
            txBuffer[tx_in++] = c;}
        else {
            tx_buffer_empty = 0;
            SBUF = c;}
        ES=1;
    }
```

I call the print function with a string text as arguement like:

```
print("Hello World");
```

I only used 2.2kb of my 32kb external memory so my conclusion is too move "Hello World" to the external memory instead of having it hardcoded in the main program.

Unfortunately my attempts actually made it worse, I did the following:

```
char xdata *msg1 = "Hello World"; // <-- this made it worse, and the external memory space was not used at all
print(msg1);
```

Than I tried:

```
char xdata msg1[] = "Hello World";
print(msg1);
```

This did increase the external memory size by 12 which is correct as the string contains 11 chars + the null. But the program memory also increased by 3. I tried different string lengths but the program memory keeps increasing by 3 bytes.

How can I solve this problem?

Addition:
I am using Keil's C compiler and I compile with favor for program size.
The uController is an FPGA chip which has an emulated 80C51 chip. For this virtual 80c51 I am writing the code. I have 32kb memory for the main program and 32kb for variables

EDIT: *msg[] was a typo, it had to be *msg

Comment: Hmm... could the 3 bytes be the actual call to the print function? 8051 programming if now far but it should not be far from *load address of msg into A register* followed with *call print*

Comment: Excuse me, I am not proficient in microcontroller programming, but by 'external memory', what is meant by that? Do you mean like the data segment of your program?

Comment: @MichaelBeer External memory is non-volatile memory which lay on a different physical place than the RAM memory. This means that declared variables may contain junk when not initialized. One needs to use the xdata keyword to make use og the extern memory. In the case of our FPGA chips, the external memory has it's own memory ICs

Comment: @bask185 Ah thanks, interesting that the compiler actually is able to optimize for this aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> char xdata *msg1 = "Hello World";
>
> char xdata msg1[] = "Hello World";

I don't think you can ever shorten your program this way, because even if the message will be accessed *from xdata*, it will be first copied there by the C runtime, fetching it **from code** (initialized data).

If you really have a lot of "print()", then you can squeeze some bytes by declaring a correct pointer type for its parameter. I explain: due to the strange architecture of the 8051, a "high level" C "generic" pointer takes three bytes - two bytes as offset, and a third byte to specify whether it points in XDATA or in CODE. Then every call to print() has to construct such a pointer.

If, for example, you declare:

> void print(char xdata *x)

now print() only accepts pointers into xdata, and only two bytes long pointers are required. Every call to print() will be simpler.

It seems that most of your texts will be constant, so they will be in code; and so the pointer type you need is **not XDATA but CODE (or what else keyword is correct)**.

Once you have declared print() like above, you will NO MORE be able to print() data which is not in the code segment; perhaps you will need another function, like

> printx(char* what)

which will accept char* from any segments, like before, but you will call this costly printx() only when needed.

Hope this helps; the 8051 is very peculiar and compilers for it are complicated (but Keil is superb). I would suggest to take a look at the generated (low level) code, may be you can spot some other memory waste. Good luck!

Addendum:______________

It happened once to me to have little room for texts. I solved nicely by applying some text compression. Given that all the texts were plain ASCII, I used characters over 127 to point to common, repeated words in the texts. For example "Hello world" can be replaced with `0x80 " world"`, if the string "Hello" is repeated a few times. Of course, the print routine must detect those special markers and manage the decompression - but this is very easy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've talked with some coworkes and it seems that I was only using half of the capacity. I assumed once that I had 0x8000 bytes for code and 0x8000 bytes for variables..... I was painfully wrong.

I get that what I want cannot really be done. I use print about 280 times. I understand that parsing a hard coded string as an arguement requires as much code as initializing a char[] variable. I only have 6 duplicate messages so I wouldn't be able to save much space anyways

Comment: If you call the function 280 times, then that is what is consuming your memory. Perhaps you can simplify some code using lookup tables and/or clever data structures to find the proper string to print instead of having so many calls.

Answer (score 0):

In short, put this line in the beginning of your source file:

```
#pragma STRING (XDATA)
```

These pages may help you understand better:

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_const.htm
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_string.htm

2018/06/25 edit:
try this line:

```
#pragma O2 STRING (XDATA)
```

as stated in the 2nd link above and this page, OMF2 should be enabled to use STRING directive
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_omf2.htm

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, unfortunatly I get a fatal compiler error:
C51 FATAL-ERROR -
  ACTION:  PARSING INVOKE-/#PRAGMA-LINE
  LINE:    #pragma STRING(XDATA) 
  ERROR:   INCOMPATIBLE CONTROL
C51 TERMINATED.

I'll read the 2 links you send me. Using the const keyword also does not decrease the program

Comment: I no longer have to fortunately. Firstly I made a mistake in the compiler settings. I was only using half the memory/ I thought I had 32kb but I have 65k.

secondly according to Keil's customer support I don't have the appropiate license to use this #pragma line.

I also doubt if it would be of any help, whether I initialize a string or pass the string as an arguent, it would still consume the same ammount of code space